# Cannot update value when wrapping SwiftUI binding in another binding

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a login code screen. This consists of 4 separate `UITextField` elements, each accepting one character. What I did is implement a system whereby every time one of the `UITextField`'s changes it will verify if all the values are filled out, and if they are update a boolean binding to tell the parent object that the code is correct.

In order to do this I wrap the `@State` variables inside a custom binding that does a callback on the setter, like this:

```
@State private var chars:[String] = ["","","",""]

...
var body: some View {
        var bindings:[Binding<String>] = []

        for x in 0..<self.chars.count {
            let b = Binding<String>(get: {
                return self.chars[x]
            }, set: {
                self.chars[x] = $0
                self.validateCode()
            })

            bindings.append(b)
        }
```

and those bindings are passed to the components. Every time my text value changes `validateCode` is called. This works perfectly.

However now I want to add an extra behavior: If the user types 4 characters and the code is wrong I want to move the first responder back to the first textfield and clear its contents. The first responder part works fine (I also manage that using `@State` variables, but I do not use a binding wrapper for those), however I can't change the text inside my code. I think it's because my components use that wrapped binding, and not the variable containing the text.

This is what my `validateCode` looks like:

```
    func validateCode() {
        let combinedCode = chars.reduce("") { (result, string) -> String in
            return result + string
        }

        self.isValid = value == combinedCode

        if !isValid && combinedCode.count == chars.count {

            self.hasFocus = [true,false,false,false]
            self.chars = ["","","",""]
        }
    }
```

`hasFocus` does its thing correctly and the cursor is being moved to the first `UITextField`. The text however remains in the text fields. I tried creating those bindings in the `init` so I could also use them in my `validateCode` function but that gives all kinds of compile errors because I am using `self` inside the getter and the setter.

Any idea how to solve this? Should I work with Observables? I'm just starting out with SwiftUI so it's possible I am missing some tools that I can use for this.

For completeness, here is the code of the entire file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CWCodeView: View {
    var value:String
    @Binding var isValid:Bool

    @State private var chars:[String] = ["","","",""]

    @State private var hasFocus = [true,false,false,false]
    @State private var nothingHasFocus:Bool = false

    init(value:String,isValid:Binding<Bool>) {
        self.value = value
        self._isValid = isValid

    }

    func validateCode() {
        let combinedCode = chars.reduce("") { (result, string) -> String in
            return result + string
        }
        self.isValid = value == combinedCode


        if !isValid && combinedCode.count == chars.count {

            self.hasFocus = [true,false,false,false]
            self.nothingHasFocus = false
            self.chars = ["","","",""]
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        var bindings:[Binding<String>] = []

        for x in 0..<self.chars.count {
            let b = Binding<String>(get: {
                return self.chars[x]
            }, set: {
                self.chars[x] = $0
                self.validateCode()
            })

            bindings.append(b)
        }


        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView (.vertical){
                VStack{
                    HStack {
                        CWNumberField(letter: bindings[0],hasFocus: self.$hasFocus[0], previousHasFocus: self.$nothingHasFocus, nextHasFocus: self.$hasFocus[1])
                        CWNumberField(letter: bindings[1],hasFocus: self.$hasFocus[1], previousHasFocus: self.$hasFocus[0], nextHasFocus: self.$hasFocus[2])
                        CWNumberField(letter: bindings[2],hasFocus: self.$hasFocus[2], previousHasFocus: self.$hasFocus[1], nextHasFocus: self.$hasFocus[3])
                        CWNumberField(letter: bindings[3],hasFocus: self.$hasFocus[3], previousHasFocus: self.$hasFocus[2], nextHasFocus: self.$nothingHasFocus)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
                .modifier(AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CWCodeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CWCodeView(value: "1000", isValid: .constant(false))
    }
}

struct CWNumberField : View {
    @Binding var letter:String
    @Binding var hasFocus:Bool
    @Binding var previousHasFocus:Bool
    @Binding var nextHasFocus:Bool

    var body: some View {
        CWSingleCharacterTextField(character:$letter,hasFocus: $hasFocus, previousHasFocus: $previousHasFocus, nextHasFocus: $nextHasFocus)
            .frame(width: 46,height:56)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(Color.init("codeBorder"), lineWidth: 1)
            )

    }
}

struct CWSingleCharacterTextField : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var character: String
    @Binding var hasFocus:Bool
    @Binding var previousHasFocus:Bool
    @Binding var nextHasFocus:Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField.init()
        //textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        textField.tintColor = .black
        textField.text = character

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        if hasFocus {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent:CWSingleCharacterTextField

        init(_ parent:CWSingleCharacterTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let result = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

            if result.count > 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.parent.hasFocus = false
                    self.parent.nextHasFocus = true
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.parent.hasFocus = false
                    self.parent.previousHasFocus = true
                }
            }

            if result.count <= 1 {
                parent.character = string
                return true
            }

            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just make a little mistake, but i cannot believe you just "started" SwiftUI ;)

1.) just build textfield one time, so i took it as a member variable instead of building always a new one
2.) update the text in updateuiview -> that's it
3.) ...nearly: there is still a focus/update problem...the last of the four textfields won't update correctly ...i assume this is a focus problem....

try this:

```
struct CWSingleCharacterTextField : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var character: String
    @Binding var hasFocus:Bool
    @Binding var previousHasFocus:Bool
    @Binding var nextHasFocus:Bool

    let textField = UITextField.init()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        //textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        textField.tintColor = .black
        textField.text = character

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {

        uiView.text = character

        if hasFocus {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent:CWSingleCharacterTextField

        init(_ parent:CWSingleCharacterTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let result = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

            if result.count > 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.parent.hasFocus = false
                    self.parent.nextHasFocus = true
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.parent.hasFocus = false
                    self.parent.previousHasFocus = true
                }
            }

            if result.count <= 1 {
                parent.character = string
                return true
            }

            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't believe me? I started this weekend ;)  I will try your solution today and let you know how it went.

Comment: because it is very tricky what you are doing and it looks a pro....!

Comment: I have been doing iOS for 10 years ;)

Comment: It works if I add DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) around the 'reset contents' code